# HP Deskjet F2400 no longer shows up in CUPS web interface

Tags: 11.10, printing

After updating to Oneiric, my printer (HP Deskjet F2400, shared) no longer appears on the cups web interface of my other machines and is not listed in apps on them (2, running Slackware 13.37), though I can print using lp -h.

Answer (score 1):

Had to run the following on the clients:

```
lpadmin -p Deskjet-F2400-series -E -v ipp://192.168.1.33/printers/Deskjet-F2400-series
```

The printer now shows up in the cups interface on clients and is listed on applications on clients.